# d3 mulitple area chart converstion to line charts

Tags: d3.js

I have this d3 chart java script

```
 this.area = d3.svg.area()                                                       .interpolate("basis")
.x(function(d) { return xS(d.Year); })
.y0(this.height)
.y1(function(d) { return yS(d[localName]); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v9k9s/LHC3R/10/

and need to convert to line chart instead of area chart any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Simply change to d3.line - https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line - from d3.area.

Main change is that d3.line only has a y function rather than y0 and y1 as it's a 1-dimensional path not 2d,

```
 this.area = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { return xS(d.Year); })
        //.y0(this.height)
        .y(function(d) { return yS(d[localName]); });
```

Later on change the color function to apply to the stroke not the fill

```
 .attr("stroke", function (d,i) { return colours(options.id); });
```

And in the css remove the fill altogether from the paths

```
  path.chart { fill: none; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LHC3R/11/

Comment: Thanks a lot :) you saved my day :)

Comment: in the given example how can I set the different y axis range for every part?

Comment: For that you'd need to first have an array of max values rather than just one max value (one per type -x,y,z,e,t) which you'd use as domains when building an array of scales (1 domain to 1 scale). Then use these scales to construct the different y axes.